# Rendering Using an array.map()

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jsx

I have a doubt with this problem, we know that arr.map() always returns an array then how exactly we are able to render elements using this here in the Code.

```
class Messages extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const msgs = [
      {id: 1, text: "Greetings!"},
      {id: 2, text: "Goodbye!"},
    ];

    return (
      <ul>
        { msgs.map(m => <li>{m.text}</li>) }
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) explains in React's documentation. Especially the [Rendering Multiple Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#rendering-multiple-components) section.

Comment: @norbitrial you should just post that as the answer.  The answer to this question should be just, "React supports and understands collections of components for exactly this use case"

Answer (score -2, accepted):

React internally makes all the child elements as children props for the parent element. 
So, it will be array of child elements wrapped under curly braces which make them inline.

eg: 
Web output

```
<ul>
   <li>Greetings</li>
   <li>Goodbye!</li>
</ul>
```

Internally in React its equal to below piece of code

```
<ul>
   {
     [ <li>Greetings</li>, <li>Goodbye!</li> ]
   }
</ul>
```

Which is equivalent to wrapping a map (returns array) in curly braces.

Comment: This is not true.  Run that through a babel transpiler; that is not the way it is interpreted.  Collections are just understood by React.

Comment: Please refer to this blog post.
https://reacttraining.com/blog/jsx-the-confusing-parts/#map-and-keys

Comment: I could claim for loop React.createElement("li") was "equal internally" too.  https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=DwPgUABBbArgNuKFjwJYgOICcCmuAXNAOwHMBnYAenSSlQ0wHsmATAIwE9cBCa2mFQTgYwyFADe45AG0UtHPiJlKNDABp5jFh2581ICAF1pAX0Fio48dRBA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=true&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Ces2016%2Ces2017%2Creact%2Cstage-0&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.9.6&externalPlugins=  they do not generate the same code or execution paths.

Comment: Actually the linked article is slightly more accurate than what you claim.  At least it holds some truth to it.  But this: "So, it will be **array of child elements wrapped under curly braces which make them inline**."  This is completely and absolutely wrong.  That is not how JSX transpiling works.

Answer (score 2):

React can render `strings`, `numbers`, and `arrays` by default. `undefined` and `null` data types will be rendered as an empty string while react cannot render an `object`. In your case you created a new array from the `msgs object` and `react` by default knows how to render values in an array. Therefore you see the result properly rendered on the screen. The ability has to do with the internal workings of React.

Answer (score 0):

Your list of items must have a unique key, the best way is to use the item ID like that.

```
 class Messages extends React.Component {
   render() {
     const msgs = [
       {id: 1, text: "Greetings!"},
       {id: 2, text: "Goodbye!"},
     ];

     return (
       <ul>
         { msgs.map(m => <li key={m.id}>{m.text}</li>) }
       </ul>
     );
   }
 }
```

If your list of elements does not have an ID you can use the index if it does not change.

```
 class Messages extends React.Component {
   render() {
     const msgs = [
       {id: 1, text: "Greetings!"},
       {id: 2, text: "Goodbye!"},
     ];

     return (
       <ul>
         { msgs.map((m, i) => <li key={i}>{m.text}</li>) }
       </ul>
     );
   }
 }
```

Comment: It's highly advised to have a  key, but it's not a _must_. The code will still work without it, it will just have a high likelihood of bugs down the line.